# SendBird create GroupChannel with file as cover

Tags: javascript, sendbird

I'm trying to create a group Channel with a cover photo,

```
this.sendBirdInstance.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds(userIds, true, this.groupName, this.groupPhotoFile, '', function (createdChannel, error) {
...
}
```

According to the documentation I can add a url or a file

> coverUrl : the file or URL of the cover image, which you can fetch to
>   render into the UI.

But when adding a file, I'm always getting : `"SendBirdException", code: 800110, message: "Invalid arguments."`

Is there a way to create a group with a file instead of a url (since I want the user to upload the file) ?

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using version  3.0.40

Comment: Are you more lucky using the [Platform API](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform#open_channel_3_create_a_channel)? Note that, as you can read in the docs, you must send a [Multipart request](https://docs.sendbird.com/platform#quick_start_4_multipart_requests). If you can send the file via REST API, then maybe it is possible to override the js check that returns the 800110 error.

Comment: Thanks David, is the API the only way ? , because in this case I'll have to check CORS and sending multipart request from javascript is not straightforward, but if you're sure there's no way using the javascript SDK i'll go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already experienced (I saw that you have created an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-JavaScript/issues/48) several days ago) the support of SendBird is kinda unreliable.

The fact that they offer [just a minified version](https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-JavaScript/blob/master/SendBird.min.js) of their JavaScript SDK (which personally I find very poor) is helping either.

Anyway, I could isolate the `createChannelWithUserIds` function:

```
! function (e, n) {
    // ... 
}(this, function () {
    // ... 
    var h = function (e) {
        for (var n in e) if (e.hasOwnProperty(n)) return !1;
        return Array.isArray(e) ? JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify([]) : JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify({})
    },
    // ... 
    A = function () { // it returns SendBird function
        // ... 
        var w = function (e) { // w is this.GroupChannel
            // ... 
            w.createChannelWithUserIds = function () {
                // ...
                // here comes the param validation (I've added spaces for a better lecture):
                if (!Array.isArray(e) || "boolean" != typeof n || "string" != typeof t && null !== t && void 0 !== t || "string" != typeof r && h(r) && null !== r && void 0 !== r || "string" != typeof a && null !== a && void 0 !== a || "string" != typeof i && null !== i && void 0 !== i) return void U(null, new p("Invalid arguments.", J.INVALID_PARAMETER), s);
                // It will return "Invalid arguments." if any of the conditions evaluates to true       
                // ... 
            }
        }
    }
    return function () {
        // ... 
    }().SendBird
});
```

You are using the function like this:

```
createChannelWithUserIds(o, n, t, r, a, s);
```

So the fourth parameter (`r`) is `coverURL`: the file with the cover picture (`this.groupPhotoFile`);

Its validation is basically saying that:

```
"string" != typeof r    // if `r` is not a string (a URL)
&& h(r)                 // and the returned value of function h(r) is true
&& null !== r           // and it is not null
&& void 0 !== r         // and it is not undefined
```

that parameter is invalid.

Your file is not a string, not null and not undefined, so everything boils down to the `h()` function:

```
var h = function (e) {
    for (var n in e) if (e.hasOwnProperty(n)) return !1;
    return Array.isArray(e) ? JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify([]) : JSON.stringify(e) === JSON.stringify({})
}
```

The function above check in first place if the object has any property what is a member of the object itself (i.e. not properties belonging to the prototype chain).
Then, if it doesn't have any own property, it checks if the stringify object/array is equal to an empty object/array.

I can't say what is the intention of the developers when validating files though this function, but a standard FILE object:

- has properties in its prototype chain, but not directly assigned to the instance, so the first condition is `true`.
- when stringify returns a empty object in all major browsers nowadays ([it was not always like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072267/how-to-serialize-file-object-to-json)), so the second condition is also `true`.

As we saw before, we need `h()` to return `false`: the validation fails if it returns `true`.

To fix this behavior you could change the `h()` function to something like:

```
var h = function( e ){
    return !(e instanceof File);
    // or return e.constructor != File;
    // or return Object.getPrototypeOf( e ) != File.prototype );
    // or return e.__proto__ != File.prototype )
    // or return e.constructor.prototype != File.prototype )
}
```

but I won't mess with it. It could be used in future versions with a different purpose.

So your best bet is to change the `createChannelWithUserIds()` function to:

- remove the call to the `h()` function from the validation.
- replace it with a call to your own file validation

To do that, you could override the function in a SendBird instance:

```
var sb = new SendBird( { appId: ... } );

sb.GroupChannel.createChannelWithUserIds = function(){ ... };
```

But it is not guarantee to work and could break in future releases, so I would just edit the SendBird.min.js file.
In other words, replace:

```
if(!Array.isArray(e)||"boolean"!=typeof n||"string"!=typeof t&&null!==t&&void 0!==t||"string"!=typeof r&&h(r)&&null!==r&&void 0!==r||"string"!=typeof a&&null!==a&&void 0!==a||"string"!=typeof i&&null!==i&&void 0!==i)return void U(null,new p("Invalid arguments.",J.INVALID_PARAMETER),s);
```

with:

```
if(!Array.isArray(e)||"boolean"!=typeof n||"string"!=typeof t&&null!==t&&void 0!==t||"string"!=typeof a&&null!==a&&void 0!==a||"string"!=typeof i&&null!==i&&void 0!==i)return void U(null,new p("Invalid arguments.",J.INVALID_PARAMETER),s);
```

In the current version (v3.0.41) you will find two coincidences of the code above: one for `createChannel` and other for `createChannelWithUserIds`, you can replace both.

Of course, editing the .js file is annoying because you will need to take care to replace the code everytime you upgrade SendGrid.
You could create an automatic task inside your CI pipeline to do it for you, thought.

Hopefully, the SendGrid developers will acknowledge your issue and fix it in a future release.

Comment: I'm getting "Invalid arguments."

Comment: Wow it works!! I'll tell sendbird about this bug :D 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to hear that Dany! I will rewrite it later as a proper answer so it is useful for more people.

Comment: Somehow late but, as promised, I have rewritten my answer with the full details.